# Creating Lua tables as like the following

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I'm trying to design such a table in lua using love2d. While I read a lot of tutorials about Lua I couldn't manage to create such a table as I didn't understand the concept. can anyone help me in creating this table?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

defining:

```
YourTable = {
  [1] = {Color1='Red',  Color2='Blue', Result='Yellow'},
  [2] = {Color1='Blue', Color2='Red',  Result='Orange'},
  [3] = ...
}
```

accessing:

```
print(YourTable[2].Color1)
```

Comment: You don't need the `[1] =` in this case.

Comment: @TomBlodget - Yes, `ID` assumed to be unique in this table.  BTW, your "double-bracketed style" is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: The answer makes some very valuable assumptions about the data, without which you'd need something like: {["ID"]=1, ["Color1"]='Red',  ["Color2"]='Blue', ["Result"]='Yellow'}, .... (I removed the previous comment due to syntax errors.)